# How to refer to the button view when clicked on in android(Kotlin)?

Tags: android, kotlin, button

So this is the button I am referring to:

```
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnBR"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#e6ebf2"
    android:onClick="setLetter"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btnBM"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnBM"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnMR" />
```

In my MainActivity file I am trying to create a function that will change the text of the button clicking on it. I have 9 different buttons(trying to make a tic tac toe game) that all will need the same functionality.

```
    package brianmason.example.tictactoe

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.view.View
    import brianmason.example.tictactoe.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
            setContentView(binding.root)

        }
        fun setLetter(view: View){
            //Trying to do the equivalent of this.setText("X") however this seems to be referring to the MainActivity and not the view. view.setText("X") also does not work.
        }
    }
```

What can I do to refer to the button that is being clicked on when using the setText function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to cast the `view` as a `Button` and then set the text.
Like this:

```
fun setLetter(view: View){
        (view as Button).text = "X"
}
```

Alternatively,  this is what you can do. Inside your xml layout, change the onClick attribute in all your buttons to the following and add a data tag:

```
<data>
        <variable name="mainViewModel"
                  type="com.example.yourappname.MainViewModel"/> <!-- The path to your ViewModel class> 
</data>

<!-- The parameter of handleClick function takes a value to identify each button. Makes sure it is unique for each button -->
<Button
        ...
        <!--The 1 donates the unique parameter to identify the button -->
        android:onClick='@{() -> mainViewModel.handleClick("1")}'/>

<Button
        ...
        android:onClick='@{() -> mainViewModel.handleClick("2")}'/>
```

Then create a ViewModel to handle the clicks:

```
class MainViewModel: ViewModel() {

        //private data so that we can only modify it inside this class 
        private val _buttonText = MutableLiveData<String>()

        //exposable data so that we can observe its changes later
        val buttonText = _buttonText as LiveData<String>
        
        /**
         *This is the function that will handle the clicks from the layout
         **/
        fun handleClick(string: String) {
            when (string) {
             // the value for buttonText can be anything here
                "1" -> _buttonText.value = "Button One clicked"  //Can be "X"
                "2" -> _buttonText.value = "Button Two clicked"   //Can be "O"
                "3" -> _buttonText.value = "Button Three clicked"  //etc
                "4" -> _buttonText.value = "Button Four clicked"
                 ...
                 ...
        }
    }
}
```

Now inside your onCreate method in your MainActivity, add  the following

```
 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            val binding =  DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this@MainActivity, R.layout.activity_main)

            //Get the ViewModel
            val mainViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

            binding.mainViewModel = mainViewModel    //Bind the ViewModel
            binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner //Set the lifecycleOwner
             
            //Observe the change made to the buttonText in the ViewModel and display its value as a Toast
            mainViewModel.buttonText.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, it, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            //You can also modify the button text here

        })



        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare a variable `private var player1Turn = true`, we'll use this variable to check whose turn is it and accordingly we mark "X" and "O" on the button.

Set onClickListner on each button as follows

```
binding.button1.setOnClickListner{
    if(button1.text != "") return@setOnClickListener
    else if(player1Turn) {
        button1.text = "X"
        player1Turn = !player1turn
    }
    else {
      button1.text = "O"
      player1Turn = !player1turn
    }
}
```

Note: I am using "X" for player 1 and "O" for player 2.
Let me know if it works.